# Sprout Forms: returning error question

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

With Sprout Forms is it possible to return an error message if a form submission is bouncing back because unique values are expected?

For example, if I have a custom HTML form called `signup` I would expect it to throw back an object called `signup` but `signup` is not defined. Also tried `form.getErrors()` but this also returns empty.

Sample form code:

```
<form class="form form--signup" method="post">

    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    {% set form = craft.sproutForms.form('signup') %}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sproutForms/entries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.url }}#newsletter">

    <input type="email" name="fields[email]" id="ft_email" placeholder="Email address" class="form__input" required>
    <button type="submit" class="button btn btn--box btn--send">Send </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies - resolved. Case sensitivity issue with variable (signUp not signup)